# Saving data to Mongodb mapping out array automatically

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, mongodb-query

I have been storing data into my mongodb collections for a while now with something like the below:

```
    const addDoc = {
        email: req.body.email,
        name: req.body.name, 
        region: req.body.region, 
        field1: req.body.accountData.field1,
        field2: req.body.accountData.field2,
        field3: req.body.accountData.field3,
        field4: req.body.accountData.field4,
        field5: req.body.accountData.field5,
   }
```

I have change the names "field1-5" just for ease of example but they all come from an array in accountData the JSON looks like the below:

```
{
    email: "email@email.com",
    name: "first name",
    region: "Europe",
    accountData:{
       field1: "field1",
       field2: "field2",
       field3: "field3",
       field4: "field4",
       field5: "field5",
    }
}
```

I was curious of what you would do if the array in accoundData had hundreds or thousands of fields, is there a way to save each field automatically to mongodb using the field name as the name in the database? This would be so you wouldnt have to manually map out:

```
field1: req.body.accountData.field1
```

thousands of times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use an object instead of an array?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski this is just how the data comes, would it be better for me to make it an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want to use [desctructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const req = {
  body: {
    email: 'aaa@aaa.aa',
    name: 'test',
    region: 'arct',
    accountData: {
      field1: 'some data',
      field2: 'some date 2',
      field3: 'another data'
    }
  }
}

const addDoc = {
  email: req.body.email,
  name: req.body.name,
  region: req.body.region,
  ...req.body.accountData
}

console.log(addDoc)
```

Comment: Amazing, I did not know about this and couldn't think of what to search to find a solution. Thanks a lot Konrad! Have a good day.